# If you tap a search tag on a question and then cancel, the tabbar shows

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

If you navigate to a question, then tap one of the tags, then hit cancel on the modal, the tabbar is shown, above the content, blocking the X answers button.

[image]
As seen here, this is the furthest i can scroll down. The "2 answers" button is hidden.

App version is 0.1.25

Comment: Nice find. I'm taking a look at this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened because the search view controller attempted to (wrongly) restore the tab bar, which is often needed, though not in this case.

**Fixed in version 0.1.26.**